# Signing binary files (not code signing)

Tags: c#, signing

Is there a way to sign binary files? I'd like to sign my zip files to protect them from modification (to prevent installation of malicious software).

Signing XML is rather easy, but I'm not so sure about binary files. Is this even possible? All I can find about that matter is code signing (which is not what I want). There is no use in buying expensive certificates, it's just to ensure that update files aren't modified when they get installed.

I figure I have to work like that: Hashing the file, generating a key pair (probably using the hash for it) and then append the signature bytes to the file.

Vice versa, reading the signature bytes and verifying the hash against the public key of the signature.

But I don't think it's that simple. Do I have to consider certain things (like with XML that you need to canonicalize)?

I do not necessarily need code, but some detailed explanation about the process (any resources that explain that thoroughly would be okay as well).

Comment: Signing is pointless without verification, how to you plan on verifying the signature is correct? If you are using a installer they normally have build in mechanisms for this like using [a catalog file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537872(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Because it shouldn't be different than with XML files. I mean, why should the public key verify correctly if the hash has changed (which happens as soon as any byte is different to the original). Certificates are - as far as I know - only used to validate the source (from whom that file comes) which in this case is pointless - it's from the developer. It's just a protection if anyone would hack the server and modify the file (so that customers don't have to fear installation of malicious software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with arbitrary binary files you can't modify their content so if you want to sign them you need to use a separate external file that contains the hash of the file you want to sign and also signs itself to prevent itself from being modified.

You then read this separate file, verify its personal signature, then verify the hash of each file it lists in its contents. You can use [Catalog Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537872(v=vs.85).aspx) built in to windows (using [MakeCat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386967(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx) to create them) or create your own following the same process.

Because you are only distributing updates, and if you are allowed to assume that the program loading the updates has not been modified, you don't need to "buy" a certificate. You could create your own "private CA", distribute that CA's certificate inside the updater, then use that Private CA's certificate to validate the catalog file.

Comment: Makes sense. Well I think that should be possible. I have an signed XML package description file which could include the key, so this should cut it perfectly well. About the certificate: Are self-signed certificates useful? After all they are not trustworthy then. Why using them anyway then?

Comment: It is not self signed, it is signed by a "Private CA", All CA certificates are "Self Signed", all being a "Installed CA" means is "I am going to trust this self signed certificate to be real". You can make your own CA and distribute it's certificate with your program.

Comment: Ah okay, understood. But in order to avoid messages saying it's untrustworthy you should consider buying one from an approved CA, right?

Comment: Nope, you can have your program install the certificate in the user's root store and it becomes just as trusted as Verisign or GoDaddy.

Comment: The only reason you **need** to buy a certificate from a established CA is you need that "foothold" in the users computer to anchor the "chain of trust". Because your program is already on the computer it can make it's own anchor and you don't need to rely on someone elses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean as "binary file", but if you talk about PE format (Windows binary executable) you can generate own signature (encrypted hash) and put it inside of PE file in the same place as Windows authenticode certificate goes. Here is an open source tool to make such modifications:
http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/disitool/

Comment: I meant files that are not plain text, but basically every file is binary (sorry for the misleading title). I already managed to sign a file by using the approach Scott Chamberlain mentioned in his answer. I already got a separate XML file where I can store the file's signature. Thanks for the info, though - might come in handy at a later point.